# Was wäre eine gute Übersetzung von engl. "attention whore" ins Deutsche?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

Ist da **Rampensau** angemessen oder unpassend?

---

*In English:*

What's a fitting translation for "attention whore" (into German)

Would **Rampensau** be fitting or inappropriate?

Comment: attention whore is an accepted anglicism where i live. "geltungssüchtig", as proposed, is good, too. Never heard it, but the meaning would fit attention whore. 'Luder' indicates a female person and is quite rude.

Comment: Und attention whore ist angemessen?

Comment: Also Rampensau ist doch eigentlich immer latent negativ besetzt, bzw. attention whore kann auch diese 'unangenehm, aber genau dieses Verhalten brauchen wir gerade'-Einschätzung wiedergeben. Viele Rampensäue sind gut anzuschauen, aber wehe man steht auch auf der Bühne...

Comment: @bukwyrm diesen latent negativen Eindruck teile ich nicht.

Comment: Wäre in Ihrem Verständnis eine Rampensau bereit den Platz im Rampenlicht zu teilen, oder nicht?

Comment: @bukwyrm kommt auf den Kontext an. Meiner Erfahrung nach kann der Begriff sowohl negativ als auch belustigend positiv verwendet werden (bspw. im Hinblick auf ein Kind das "absolut nicht schüchtern" ist, ohne abwertenden Kontext). Im negativen Kontext wäre es vermutlich unwahrscheinlich, daß die besagte Rampensau das Rampenlicht freiwillig mit anderen teilen würde. Oder konkreter: ich teile nicht die Auffassung daß der Begriff _allein_ negativ gebraucht wird, was ich bei "attention whore" bisher immer erlebt hatte. Daher ja meine Frage ob Rampensau nicht unpassend wäre.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Rampensau isn't appropriate because it just expresses passion which is not a negative ambition, and *-sau* is meant here like in *coole Sau*. I would suggest *geltungssüchtiges Luder* or *Sie ist aufmerksamkeitsgeil*. (taken from [here](http://dict.leo.org/forum/viewUnsolvedquery.php?idThread=465402&idForum=2&lang=de&lp=ende))

I understand *Rampensau* as *stage tiger* or *stage lion*.

Comment: Why is it not appropriate, though? Too harsh? "geltungssüchtiges Luder" (or "Person") sounds quite good, though. Thanks.

Comment: *Rampensau* is not appropriate because it does carry both, a positive and negative connotation based on context. With `attention whore`, I cannot think of a positive context I have heard this being used in. I'd go with falk's *geltungssüchtiges Luder* or the adjective *aufmerksamkeitsgeil*.

Comment: @0xC0000022L: to use *Person* is a good thing because it sounds much less offending but still deprecative

Answer (score 4):

Wenn es kein Nomen sein muss, wären auch Adjektive wie "aufmerksamkeitssüchtig" oder "aufmerksamkeitsheischend" möglich.

Oder man benutzt eine Phrasen wie:

> muss ständig im Mittelpunkt stehen

Comment: Ein Substantiv wäre mir am liebsten, aber natürlich geht auch ein zusammengesetzter Begriff. Danke.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it might not be perfectly appropriate `Rampensau` still feels like the best available translation in terms of usage. Especially `geltungssüchtiges Luder` sounds a bit roundabout.